# No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options - ionic6

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic

Estoy construyendo una app movil con ionic 6 y estoy usando @angular/fire y firebase y por alguna razón no logra inyectarlo la configuracion de firebase en app.module, seguí los pasos de de ésta pagina `https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/version-7-upgrade.md`

[image: Es el error que me muestra cuando inicio la aplicación de ionic]

```
import { firebaseConfig } from '../environments/environment.prod';
import {  provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideFirestore, getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(firebaseConfig)),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
  ]
...
```